# Laravel and index.php without Clean URLs

Tags: php, laravel-4, clean-urls

Ok, I'm going nuts trying to work this out.  I am NOT able to use Clean URLs for my application (grumble), which I'm building with Laravel 4.1 to run on a Windows server.
My login page is giving me grief. It lives at the root of my application, https:\localhost\EPHY. The URL on the login form is defined via

```
{{ Form::open( array( 'url' => '/index.php/login', 'role'=>'form', 'class'=>'form-horizontal' ) ) }}
```

When I log in, that URL takes me to https:\localhost\EPHY\index.php\main. Groovy.

I log out, which triggers `Redirect::to('/')` and I get shunted back to the login page, but with a URL of https:\localhost\EPHY\index.php. As a result, when I log in again, I wind up pointed to https:\localhost\EPHY\index.php\index.php\main (note the doubled index.php).

So, what can I feed to Redirect::to() short of a static URL (a problem since I've got both local and production environments) that will send it back to https:\localhost\EPHY rather than https:\localhost\EPHY\index.php?  I can't really do an absolute URL it because I've got development and production environments.  Alternately, what can I feed my form so that it will add index.php to the action if it is missing, but not if it is present?

Yes, I would much prefer to do clean URLs...

Comment: You should specify what web server you're using. "Windows server" is an OS, not a web server. WAMP? XAMPP? IIS?

Comment: Sorry, valid point.  I'm on IIS 6, and we've hit a brick wall getting IIRF to work, so I'm trying to live with index.php in my URLs.

I have a slightly brittle workaround in place that attempts to determine where within the application the requester is coming from, but what I really need is some way of recovering the originally requested URL, and that also appears to be missing from IIS 6.